# How to get information on all types of data declared in a given package

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How can I use information from the dictionary views to get information on all types of data declared in a given package in Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PL/Scope ...

```
alter session set plscope_settings = 'IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

... and recompile the package (`UTL_LOG` in my case) ...

```
alter package utl_log compile;
alter package utl_log compile body;
```

... and then query the `user_identifiers` view ...

```
select name, type, object_name, object_type, line, col
from user_identifiers
where object_name = 'UTL_LOG'
    and usage = 'DECLARATION'
    and type not in ('VARIABLE','FUNCTION','FORMAL IN','FORMAL OUT','CONSTANT','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE')
;
```

... which would (in my case) yield ...

```
NAME                TYPE    OBJECT_ OBJECT_ LINE COL
------------------- ------- ------- ------- ---- ---
ARR_SOME_COLLECTION VARRAY  UTL_LOG PACKAGE   19   6
REC_SOME_RECORD     RECORD  UTL_LOG PACKAGE   15   6
TYP_LOG_CODE        SUBTYPE UTL_LOG PACKAGE    8   9
```

**Please note** that PL/Scope can be used for **any** identifier declared/defined in **any** program unit, not only for data type declarations.

Comment: I never tried it. Nice. My solution seems to be more of a work, perhaps an alternative. There are so many ways of doing same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how a package looks like run: `desc PACKAGE_NAME`:

```
SQL> desc dbms_output
PROCEDURE DISABLE
PROCEDURE ENABLE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 BUFFER_SIZE                    NUMBER(38)              IN     DEFAULT
PROCEDURE GET_LINE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LINE                           VARCHAR2                OUT
 STATUS                         NUMBER(38)              OUT
PROCEDURE GET_LINES
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LINES                          TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) OUT
 NUMLINES                       NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
PROCEDURE GET_LINES
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 LINES                          DBMSOUTPUT_LINESARRAY   OUT
 NUMLINES                       NUMBER(38)              IN/OUT
PROCEDURE NEW_LINE
PROCEDURE PUT
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 A                              VARCHAR2                IN
PROCEDURE PUT_LINE
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 A                              VARCHAR2                IN
```

If you want to get all dependencies see [ALL_DEPENDENCIES](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm):

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package t1_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure fake_proc;
  4* end t1_pkg;
SQL> /

Package created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace package body t1_pkg
  2  as
  3    procedure fake_proc
  4    as
  5      l_count number(10);
  6    begin
  7      select count(*)
  8        into l_count
  9        from user_objects;
 10    end fake_proc;
 11* end t1_pkg;
SQL> /

Package body created.

SQL> select referenced_name, referenced_type from user_dependencies where name = 'T1_PKG';

REFERENCED_NAME REFERENCED_TYPE
--------------- ------------------
STANDARD        PACKAGE
USER_OBJECTS    SYNONYM
T1_PKG          PACKAGE
```

Comment: But how does it lists all the data types inside the package? OP wants to get an output of the data types declared in a package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any dynamic view to directly get that information.

I am thinking of querying `ALL_SOURCE` using REGULAR EXPRESSION to find all possible `DATA TYPE` in the `DESCRIPTION` column. Put the `PACKAGE NAME` in the where clause as `WHERE name = package_name`

**NOTE**

Based on other answer, there seems to be a direct way, so my solution would be an alternative. As the saying goes, there are many ways of doing the same task, this is one of them.

Comment: Nice. Then my solution becomes an alternative, rather more of work ;-)

Comment: You like it? Then click on the "upvote". :-) We're all just a bunch of reputation-junkies. ;-)

Comment: I already did. Let's see if OP and others like my alternate solution.

Comment: Unless there is a special case, regular expressions are unable to parse PL/SQL.  Parsing PL/SQL reminds me of [this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Well, that question is about reading html tags. In this case, the datatypes are in plain text in the description column. Though I am not a huge fan of regex as they are high resource consuming tool, but in this case it will be simpler to write.