# Automate bulk of update queries in pl\sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

For frequent period of time, i'm doing same process of updating few tables with consecutive values. Hope to make this simple an example below,

```
UPDATE   Table_1 SET   vchar_val = REPLACE (vchar_val, '.360/', '.370/'),
      WHERE   vchar_val LIKE 'http://services%.360/%'
     AND c_version IN ('ALL', 'N/A', '37.0');
```

For 37th version, i'm replacing the places where '36' with '37'. The same i'll do for '38' and it continues...This is making me bore and time consuming process as i've 50 plus records like this for different tables for which i'm manually editing all update queries.

So i planned to write a scheduler which i can trigger for each version by giving input as previous version and current version, in which i'll put all this update queries.

Here comes the place where i struck, if i go by giving version values as input, i'm supposed to introduce local parameter to store. HOW CAN I ASSIGN THAT LOCAL VARIABLE TO MY UPDATE SCRIPT.??????

I go with concatenate the texts like

```
  REPLACE (vchar_val, '.'+ @PrevVersion  +'/', '.'+ @CurrentVersion  +'/')
```

PrevVer** & CurrentVer** is my local variable with values .360 & .370 resp.

I think i miss quiet piece of code in this snippet as i'm getting error when running this.

Please help me guys to rearrange this code to automate the query or ur comments to do this job in any alternative way...

Thanks

-VIno

Comment: `REPLACE (vchar_val, '.'+ @PrevVersion  +'/', '.'+ @CurrentVersion  +'/')` is no Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: then how can i make this happen in pl\sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
begin 
  for i in 36 .. 50 loop
    UPDATE   Table_1 
    SET vchar_val = REPLACE (vchar_val, '.'|| i ||'0/', '.'|| i+1 ||'0/')
    WHERE vchar_val LIKE 'http://services%.'|| i ||'0/%'
    AND c_version IN ('ALL', 'N/A', i+1 ||'.0'); 
  end loop;
end;
```

Of course you could do that in one single update with some fancy reg_exp, but I leave that exercice to another fellow stackoverflower :)

Comment: thnks mate. but i'm not gona update the version in single shot. the query seems to update 36,37 till 50 in single shot. can i take this i as local variable which gets value from table where i insert my version?????? If so i'll insert correspondin versions for every release which intern update the query..how can it could be??

Answer (score 0):

Local variable:

```
declare
  my_local_valiable number;
begin
  update my_table ... ;
  commit;
end;
```

Autoincrement: [sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm)

```
update table_1 set my_field = '.' || my_sequence.nextval where ...;
```

**UPD**

1. Number always in the same position (for example, 2 digits, 10th and 11th symbols in the string):

   `update table_1 set my_field = substr(my_field, 1, 9) || to_char(to_number(substr(my_field, 10, 2)) + 1) || substr(my_field, 12);`

This converts string 'abracadab29ra' to 'abracadab30ra'.
The same with `replace`:

```
update table_1 set my_field = replace(my_field, substr(my_field, 10, 2), to_char(to_number(substr(my_field, 10, 2)) + 1));
```

2. Number always follows after a string `'value = '` and has two digits:

   `update table_1 set my_field = replace(my_field, substr(my_field, instr(my_field, 'value = ', 1) + 8, 2), to_char(to_number(substr(my_field, instr(my_field, 'value = ', 1) + 8, 2)) + 1))`

This converts string 'my value = 33' to 'my value = 34'.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. I'm beginner in Pl\sql. Quite confused with ur code. In your update query, you are setting my_field column directly. But in my case, i need to replace like particular word in a sentence.
Replace(my_field, '.360/','.370/')

*May be silly qn

Comment: Do you need to find a number in a certain position in the string and add another number to it? Then you need describe a way to define its position. You can use `instr` and `substr` functions. I will add an example bit later.

Comment: Exactly. Need to find a number in varchar and replace with other. Concantenate doesn't work??